# Google Sheets - Create SKU that automates content into separate columns

Tags: function, google-sheets, automation, sku

I would like to create a column (SKU) in my Google sheets CSV that when data is manually input in each cell, it will automatically fill out the content in 3 other columns (Title, Colour, Size).

I have created an example CSV with the necessary columns highlighted.

`Column B - Product title` `Column I - Colour` `Column K - Size` `Column N - SKU`

**Example SKU Inputs (Manually entered into column N)**

`L24-1-000` `C-2-150`

**Breakdown of values assigned to each section:**

`L24 = Lightweight trainers`  `S24 = Sandals`

`1 = Blue` `2 = Red`

`000 = 0`
`150 = 1.5`

**Output (Automated in columns B, I and K)**

`'Lightweight trainers', 'Blue', '0'`

`'Sandals', 'Red', '1.5'`

**Link to CSV**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E6NypRcWk4kR7WGsyEzt7Uuja8dU7SaszT9lvJPpHcg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you have a lookup section where you defined all these sections and their counterparts?

Comment: I only have examples at the moment, but these are highlighted in the second tab in the Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

B1: `=arrayformula(IF(A1:A="Handle","Title",IF(INDEX(SPLIT(N1:N, "-"),,1)="L32","Lightweight Trainers", IF(INDEX(SPLIT(N1:N, "-"),,1)="S24","Sandals", "Boots"))))`

I1: `=arrayformula(IF(A1:A="Handle","Option1 Value",IF(LEN(INDEX(SPLIT(N1:N, "-"),,2))>1,"Multicoloured",IF(INDEX(SPLIT(N1:N, "-"),,2)=1,"Blue",IF(INDEX(SPLIT(N1:N, "-"),,2)=2,"Red",IF(INDEX(SPLIT(N1:N, "-"),,2)="C","Cream",))))))`

K1: `=arrayformula(IF(A1:A="Handle","Option2 Value",MID(N1:N,LEN(N1:N) - 2,3)))`

Comment: That works perfectly for Column B and Column I, thank you! I'm not sure about column K though.

Comment: I understand correctly, you want to display 000, 100, 150, 200, 250 instead of 0, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5?

Comment: I have corrected the formula for K1. Now "000, 100, 150" etc. are displayed.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to edit the colour codes and title codes in the second tab? Or will I have to update the formulas every time I want to add a new colour or title?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227641/discussion-between-boris-baublys-and-tom).

Answer (score 1):

I want to propose to you an alternative solution to your problem. You can use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to modify and update your Spreadsheet. With this proposal, you can easily add new codes for *titles* and *colors* and different new features that are only available using Apps Script.

In this case, you need to open Apps Script clicking on `Tools > Script editor` and you will see the script editor. It is based on [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp) and it allows you to create, access, and modify Google Sheets files with a service called [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

In the code that I am attaching you, there is a function called [onEdit] that is called each time that a user modifies the value of any cell in the Spreadsheet. Thanks to that trigger you can write new values in your column `SKU` and the others can be updated simultaneously. You just need to replace the initial function with the following code, and adapt a few things, I have added comments to help you to understand everything:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
 
 const sheetName = 'abc' // name of your main sheet
 const col = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('N:N').getColumn() // sku column
 
// call the function that updates the columns only in the sku column has been updated
 if ( 
   e.source.getSheetName() == sheetName &&
   e.range.columnStart == col &&
   e.range.columnEnd == col)
 {
   main(sheetName) // update function
 }
}
 
 
function main(sheetName){
 // sku
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName)
 var sku = ss.getRange('N2:N').getValues().filter(String) // N: column ok sku
 var last_row = sku.length+1
  // Title
 title = [...sku]
 title.forEach(title_func)
 ss.getRange('I2:I'+last_row).setValues(title) 
 
 // Color
 color = [...sku]
 color.forEach(color_func)
 ss.getRange('K2:K'+last_row).setValues(color)
 
 // Size
 size = [...sku]
 size.forEach(size_func)
 ss.getRange('M2:M'+last_row).setNumberFormat('@').setValues(size)
}

function title_func(item, index, arr){
 const code = item[0].split('-')[0]
 var titles = {
   'L32':'Lightweight Trainers',
   'S24':'Sandals',
   'T19':'Boots',
   'T1':'Test' 
 }
 arr[index] = [titles[code]]
}

function color_func(item, index, arr){
 const code = item[0].split('-')[1]
 var colors = {
   '1':'Blue',
   '2':'Red',
   '1M':'Multicoloured',
   'C':'Cream',
   'O':'Orange',
   'T':'Test'
 }
 arr[index] = [colors[code]]
}

function size_func(item, index, arr){
 const code = item[0].split('-')[2]
 arr[index] = [code]
}
```

### Reference

- [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp)
- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [Simple Triggers: onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)